# Toffoli gates with Hadamard coins (QISKIT)

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, circuit-construction

I am creating the following circuit with Qiskit (2Toffoli gates controlled with coins) [image]

And to set the coins for one iteration of the circuit i do the following :

```
qsubnodes = QuantumRegister(2)
qsubnodes = QuantumRegister(2)
qc.h(subnode[0])
qc.h(subnode[1])
```

and then for the first Toffoli gate:

```
qc.ccx(subnode[0], subnode[1], *q)
```

and the second toffoli gate (which is the issue) :

```
qc.h(subnode[0])
qc.h(subnode[1])
qc.x(subnode[1]) // to invert the coin to control for 0 (as shown in the circuit)
qc.ccx(subnode[0], subnode[1], *q)
```

Is it the right way of inverting the coin for the second toffoli ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your circuit diagram, the second Toffoli should act in case "lower" qubit is in state $|1\rangle$ and "upper" one in state $|0\rangle$. Since Toffoli acts only in case both inputs are in state $|1\rangle$, you have to invert "upper" qubit, or in other words to apply $X$ there.

**So it seems that your construction is right.** *To test this, try to prepare circuit containing one Toffoli gate with $X$ applied on one of its input. Set a input of the circuit to $|01\rangle$ or $|10\rangle$ depending on which Toffoli's input is neggated and try to measure Toffoli's output; you should get $|1\rangle$.*

Comment: Thanks man, sure i will test with your inputs